# issue:two weblogic managed server inserting data in table at same time

Tags: java, oracle, jvm, weblogic

I am using weblogic and we have two managed server. JAVA Application is having a thread schedule at 9:00 am to insert data into table.Since we have two parallel managed server it is inserting data twice  sometime.Please help me out. both managed server need to be up always.

Answer (score 1):

You could implement some 'lock'.

When the first server starts the process it locks the 'lock'
and then the second server wont acquire the 'lock' and should give up.

When the first server finishes it would release the lock.

Comment: since both the server will have replica of application they are inserting data into table at same time